# Inherited fields not showing up in Item

Tags: templates, inheritance

I have an item that has a template with 2 base templates, the field of one of these templates is not showing up on the item, I verified that I'm using the correct template, has this ever occurred with anyone?

Given that the field is a multilist field.

This is the Inheritance for the main template
[image: This is the Inheritance for the main template]

And this is the base template definition
[image: And this is the base template definition]

Comment: Can an admin see the field? It's possible the user has access denied somehow (Field read access denied to the template with the multilist field, read access denied to the multilist field or field section).

Comment: I'm an admin and I can't see the field on the item, but can see it on the template

Comment: Are fields showing up on the standard values item?

Comment: @Roman weirdly enough no, not even on the standard values

Comment: can you provide a screen shot of your definition?

Comment: @Roman added images, please let me know if you need anymore

Comment: By chance do the two inherited templates share the same field name,Topics?

Comment: @ChrisAuer No, it's the only Topics field

Answer (score 2):

to verify this scenario and root cause, can you please do this activity.

1. Change the field name and display name of both the fields just for testing purpose, You can add an abbreviation like Filed A and Field B.

   2. Search those field under inheritance section
      [image]

Let me know if you are not able to find these fields there

Comment: We use TDS to sync any sitecore changes, could it be the culprit?

Comment: @Muradious - yes this could be a culprit If you are not able to see after the TDS sync and able to see after adding manually then yes it's